# Conditional Typing with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript3.0

I have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` as follow:

```
interface IClassA {
   functionA: ()=> void
}

class ClassA implements IClassA{
  functionA(){
    console.log('hello world A')
  }
}


interface IClassB {
   functionB: ()=> void
} 

class ClassB implements IClassB{
  functionB() {
    console.log('hello world B')
  }
}
```

I have another function that needs to takes an instance of `ClassA` or `ClassB` as parameter as shown below.

```
function sayHello(object) {
   // ...
}
```

How can I type the `object` in to access to the function `functionA` or `functionB` depending on the instance of the class being use? The code below won’t work:

```
function sayHello(object: IClassA | IClassB)
```

I don't want to use the generic `any` type. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `functionA` in the object before trying to invoke it.

Example ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGEA2cDOOCCyA3gFDLIwCuICYwA9iPgFzIAUAlALwB8yAbvWAATEgF8SJBNjzIsuAsmABbAA6YIyiOBxp5eQqXJUadRvk5HyyBIxz0NAOkz0A5mwDkACwiYXyAHd6KExhZHwPDjJkCQkSUEhYRBQMGRwAIWJok1oGEHTWTl4BIVExZElpBTk0zJV1TW0wXVSFTKscs3zOLOsbOwcIZzdPHz96QODQ5HTI6NjJTrzkHDgATwAJXxc2egAjACtWVoNkAB89Wo5epRh2DyXzDyUQZH2D66tyd8dHpk55uISEA)):

```
function sayHello(obj: IClassA | IClassB) {
  if ('functionA' in obj) {
    obj.functionA()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

You can actually use the `|` operator to create a union type. If your classes have separate logic, you can use the `instanceOf` syntax to check your class before running class specific code.

```
function sayHello(input: ClassA | ClassB) : string {
  if (input instanceof ClassA) {
    input.A();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Property 'functionA' does not exist on type 'ClassA | ClassB'.
  Property 'functionA' does not exist on type 'ClassB'`

Comment: @lomse I've updated my answer as well. Please take a look.

Comment: Yeah this looks great. Thanks